# How to extract Email and Phone number from same column and make it two column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a dataset where contact column has data like this

```
|    id     |     contact                                    |
|     ---    |     ------------------------------------------     |
|     1      |     951-719-9170ZoeWellish@superrito.com           |
|     2      |     PamelaSHill@cuvox.de+1 (217) 569-3204          |
|     3      |     XiuxiuChang@einrot.com1 408 778 3236           |
|     4      |     AnnikaVaara@rhyta.com312-719-7238              |
|     5      |     XiuxiuChang@einrot.com1 408 778 3236          |
|     6      |     AnenechiChidi@armyspy.com+1 (205) 417-8095     |
```

I need to extract email and phone number in a separate column. How can I do this like bellow.

```
|     id     |     Phone             |     Another header            |
|     --     |     -----------------     |      --------------------------    |
|     1      |     951-719-9170          |     ZoeWellish@superrito.com      |
|     2      |     +1 (217) 569-3204     |     PamelaSHill@cuvox.de          |
|     3      |    1 408 778 3236        |     XiuxiuChang@einrot.com        |
|     4      |     312-719-7238          |     AnnikaVaara@rhyta.com         |
|     5      |     1 408 778 3236        |     XiuxiuChang@einrot.com        |
|     6      |     +1 (205) 417-8095     |     AnenechiChidi@armyspy.com     |
```

Comment: Hi @Jay, welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and take a [tour] of Stackoverflow. When asking a question, please ensure that you also provide your attempt at the code and ask about issues with that approach or alternatives. Questions like `I want this output from this input` are not well received. Thanks!

Comment: How is this dataset generated? Because the phone numbers are sometimes before the email and other times after te email, things are being overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample it would be done this way:

```
df['Phone'] = df['contact'].str.extract(r'([+]?[0-9]+[\s+]?[\(]?[\-]?[0-9]+[\)]?[\s+]?[0-9]+[\s+]?[\-]?[0-9]+)')
df['E-mail'] = df['contact'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)')
```

Output:

```
0   951-719-9170ZoeWellish@superrito.com            ZoeWellish@superrito.com    951-719-9170
1   PamelaSHill@cuvox.de+1 (217) 569-3204           PamelaSHill@cuvox.de    +1 (217) 569-3204
2   XiuxiuChang@einrot.com1 408 778 3236            XiuxiuChang@einrot.com  1 408 778 3236
3   AnnikaVaara@rhyta.com312-719-7238               AnnikaVaara@rhyta.com   312-719-7238
4   XiuxiuChang@einrot.com1 408 778 3236            XiuxiuChang@einrot.com  1 408 778 3236
5   AnenechiChidi@armyspy.com+1 (205) 417-8095      AnenechiChidi@armyspy.com   +1 (205) 417-8095
```

I believe your dataset is larger, so you should test it and add some signs if it is necessary. I am not able to predict all possible phone formats in your dataset.